# How to start back at beginning of arraylist in a while loop?

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop

I'm trying to solve a puzzle that goes like this: 100 people stand in a circle. The first person kills the person next to him and hands the gun to the next person. Which person is left at the end?

This is what I have so far, but when I run it, it shows an out of bounds exception. I realized that when I write people.remove(i+1), the program runs to the end of the arraylist and has no way to start back at the beginning to continue the pattern. How do I do this?

Thanks for any help!

```
  private void btnEnterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int input = Integer.parseInt(txtInput.getText());
    ArrayList <Integer> people = new ArrayList <> ();

    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        people.add(i);
    }
    while (people.size() != 0) {
        int i = 1;
        people.remove(i+1);
        i++;
    } 

    for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
        lblOutput.setText(" " + people.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: You could use a `iterator` and simply remove each second person ...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: is there such a thing as a "circular" iterator?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You could probably make one, but I guess you could just keep iterating until you only had one person left...

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get an out of bound exception is that you check the size to be non-zero, but the call of `remove(i+1)` with `i` set to `1` means removing from the third spot in the list, which may not be there. Only the initial element at index zero is guaranteed to be there.

Also note that `i++` has no effect, because `i` is reset back to `1` at the top of the loop's body.

With the condition of `people.size() != 0` the only guaranteed thing is that you would be able to remove at index zero. However, this is rather inefficient, because all elements past that index need to be copied. This makes removal an O(n<sup>2</sup>), which could be slow when the list is really long.

Generally, though, the idiomatic way of managing removals from a list is using `ListIterator<T>` for removal of zero to a few items, or copying into a separate list and replacing the original list with the new one when you need to remove a significant portion of the list.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the problem, you need to remove every second person from the list until only one person remains.

The basic problem with your current implementation, is, first, you don't do any range checking (how do you know an element actually exists at `i+1`) and secondly, you loop until the list is empty, which isn't what you really want.

The basic requirement could use compounding loops, the outer loop checks the size of the list and keeps looping while the size of the `List` is greater then `1`, the second loop processes the list, removing every other person from the list.  Note, I don't reset the `hasGun` flag in the outer loop, this means that on each iteration of the inner loop, the gun continues to pass to the next survivor.

```
ArrayList<Integer> people = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    people.add(i);
}

boolean hasGun = true;
while (people.size() > 1) {
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = people.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print("> " + iterator.next());
        if (!hasGun) {
            // You get shot...
            iterator.remove();
            System.out.println(" got shot");
        } else {
            System.out.println(" shoots");
        }
        hasGun = !hasGun;
    }
}

for (Integer person : people) {
    System.out.println(person);
}
```

This example also makes uses the `List`'s `Iterator`, this over comes, in part, the issue of the array out of bounds, but you could also use a `for-next` loop and the `hasGun` flag as well.

Answer (score 0):

To circulate through your array with indexing, use the remainder operator:

```
int actual = 0;
while (people.size() != 1) {
    people.remove( (actual+1) % people.size() );
    actual = (actual+1) % people.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just think an `ArrayList` is not the best data structure for this problem. I find a `LinkedList` would be more fit. Actually, I found a very easy recursive solution using one. Have a look at this code:

```
public class Main {

    public static int kill(LinkedList<Integer> people) {
        assert people.size() > 0;
        System.out.println("people: " + people);

        if (people.size() < 3)
            return people.getFirst();
        else {
            System.out.println("kill: " + people.remove(1));
            people.addLast(people.removeFirst());
            return kill(people);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> people = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i <=100; i++) {
            people.add(i);
        }
        int survivor = kill(people);
        System.out.println("Last survivor: " + survivor);
    }  
}
```

I just remove (kill?) the second member on the list and send the first one back to the end of the list. This process can be repeated until there are 2 people left, in which case you can guess the last survivor will be the first one in the list cause he will kill the second person.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to resolve this problem, I would create my own `Person` class with a `next` property pointing to the next person.

`Person` class:

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private Person next;

    public Person(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public Person getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }

    public void setNext(Person next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void killNext() {
        this.next = this.next.next;
    }
}
```

Once that is in place, it's trivial to setup a circular set of linked persons.  The algorithm then simply becomes looping each person by following the `next` property, killing the `next` person on each iteration. And the loop exits when the `next` property points to himself, indicating that there is no one left.

Algorithm:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Setup 100 persons in a linked circle.
    Person startingPerson = new Person(1);
    Person currentPerson = startingPerson;
    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
        currentPerson.setNext(new Person(i));
        currentPerson = currentPerson.getNext();
    }
    currentPerson.setNext(startingPerson);

    // Loop around until a single person is left.
    currentPerson = startingPerson;
    while (currentPerson != currentPerson.getNext()) {
        currentPerson.killNext();
        currentPerson = currentPerson.getNext();
    }

    System.out.println("Surviving person: " + currentPerson.getId());
}
```

Output:

> Surviving person: 73